# React material table wont filter anymore nor pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

im using the material table library  for react  at first it was working greatly with sorting filtring and pagination now the pagination and the columns are not clickable any more ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
   <div style={{ width: "100%", padding: "30px" }}>
 <Link
    to='/croisiere/add-croisiere'
  style={{
    width: "5rem",
   backgroundColor: "#2089DB",
    position: "absolute",
  top: " 0.5rem",
  right: " 2rem",
  textAlign: "center",
  fontSize: "1.5rem",
  textDecoration: "none",
  color: "white",
   }}
  >
  {" "}
   +
  </Link>
   <br />
   <MaterialTable
    localization={{
    body: {
       editRow: {
      deleteText:
          "êtes-vous sûr que vous voulez supprimer ce croisiere",
      },
  },
 }}
 title='Liste des croisieres'
 columns={state.columns}
 data={state.data}
  options={{
      pageSize: 10,
  filtering: true,
   actionsColumnIndex: -1,
  headerStyle: {
     backgroundColor: "rgb(32,137,219)",
    color: "#FFF",
   },
 }}
 actions={[
     {
    icon: "visibility",
    tooltip: "voir cruise",
     onClick: (event, rowData) =>
      props.history.push(`/cruise/view-cruise/${rowData._id}`),
   },
    {
      icon: "storage",
    tooltip: "voir stock",
    onClick: (event, rowData) =>
      props.history.push(`/gestion-stock/cabins-stock/${rowData._id}`),
   },
    {
      icon: "photo",
    tooltip: "voir gallery",
      onClick: (event, rowData) =>
        props.history.push(`/cruise/view-cruise/gallery/${rowData._id}`),
    },
    ]}
    editable={{
  onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
        setState((prevState) => {
          console.log(oldData);
          const data = [...prevState.data];
          data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
          deleteCruise(oldData._id);
          return { ...prevState, data };
          });
        }, 600);
      }),
     }}
  />
 </div>
```